# Optional parameters in query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using Meteor on a projeot. How to make a query in mongodb with optional parameters?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Try giving an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a form with all fields of collection, if the User fill in only one field it should return documents that match the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of building a selector based on the values in a form:

```js
var firstName = $.trim($('#first-name').val());
var lastName = $.trim($('#last-name').val());

var selector = {};

if (firstName)
  selector['profile.firstName'] = firstName;

if (lastName)
  selector['profile.lastName'] = lastName;

Meteor.users.find(selector);
```