# How to retrieve data under multiple query parameters using mongodb and javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am learning to use mongodb and javascript to send requests to a database. I am provided an example for a single parameter query. How could I modify this to take 4 or 5 parameters?

````
    console.log(req.query);
    const filter = req.query._id === undefined
        ? {}
        : { _id: req.query._id };
    users.findUsers(filter, '', 0)
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user)
            res.send(user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            res.send({ error: 'Request failed' });
        });

});```
````

Comment: What is the question, how to send more parameters or how to use more parameters into the query?

Comment: @J.F. I want to know how this could be rewritten to allow for things other than id to passed as query parameters.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26004122/2282634